# Drupal 7 get images from content type

Tags: drupal-7

in my static html site i have:

```
 <li><a href="img/img2.jpg" rel="gallery"  
class="pirobox_gall" title=""><img src="img/img2.jpg" alt=""/>
</a></li>
```

How in Drupal 7 I can get links to images from content type named Galery with fields: title and field_img(IMAGE). Need PHP code...

for example (its not working):

```
<?php
  $mycontent = getcontentby_name('Galery');
  foreach ($mycontent as $pic)
  {
     $link_to_pic = $pic['field_img']['link'];
     print $link_to_pic;   
  }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the node in which you have your image/images by node_load($node_id), in this object you will have almost all the information related to that particular node.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $result = db_query('SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :ntype', array(':ntype' => 'galery'));

    foreach ($result as $record) {
    $node = node_load($record->nid);
    print '<img src="';
    print file_create_url($node->field_img['und'][0]['uri']);
    print '" alt=""/>';
    print file_create_url($node->field_img['und'][0]['uri']);
    }
?>
```

this code if 1 record of 'galery' - 1 image.